# How to keep the iPad not in Sleep mode

Tags: objective-c, ipad

If my app is in background mode then also I don't want my iPad will not go into sleep mode, Kindly let me know how could I manage this.

Comment: What research have you done?  What have you tried?

Comment: I did not get any reference for the same.

Answer (score 0):

to preventing iPad from sleep

```objective-c
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am ok with this code & already done the same here. If the app is in background, is it possible to keep the iPad alive.

Comment: As per my requirement I have to make the iPad screen alive utill a stuff will be done. I have added the code "[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;". After my task completed I have to make the iPad auto lock settings as it was. That's why I have again write the [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO; after the task completation. But the it's not changing the setting at all. It's still alive as the set time in the settings section. Any positive response will be highly appreciated.